# scala parse a string into a Tree to use in a quasi quote

Tags: scala, scala-quasiquotes

I was wondering if i could perform a sort of a nested quasi quote evaluation.

Let's say i have a function call

```
q"${function(args)}"
```

That returns `"add(x,y)"` (a string)

How can i make it evaluate this?

Something like

```
val a = q"""${q"${function(args)}"}"""
```

The problem here is that the first evaluation of the quasi quote is return a String which than leads to nothing being performed in the second evaluation.

Comment: What result `Tree` are you looking for?

Comment: basically i wanted to parse a string into a `Tree`. Is this possible?

Comment: Okay, but what _exact_ `Tree` do you want to get from it?

Comment: a tree that can be evaluated in a quasi quote in the form `q"$tree"`

so tree would be something like `val tree = add(x,y)`